# Domain redirection in htaccess not working

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

I have changed domain on the Magento store, however I need to still keep old domain urls accessible and redirected to new domain urls.

for example. 
old-domain.com/products  should redirect to new-domain.com/products

This is from my current htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

#  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.com$ [OR]
#  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old-domain\.com$
#  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

as you can see, I tried 2 versions,

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old-domain\.com$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old-domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But none of them work. 
Yes, I have disabled caching in Magento and yes, just in any case, I still flush the cache in Magento and I clear cache in browser too.

I dont know if this matters but anyways. 
Both new and old domains are controlled by godaddy, with its default nameservers, and both domains have @ record pointed to my server IP address.

Please help : )

Note: of course, I have real domains in the htaccess instead of old-domain.com and new-domain.com

Currently any kind of url with old domain, just redirects to homepage of new domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this one:

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643270/using-htaccess-rewrite-rules

should be useful.
Have you enabled mod_rewrite?

Oh I found reason why it didn't works for You.
Please try something like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.new-domain.com$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

EDIT:

here are parameters You can use:

- C (chained with next rule)
- CO=cookie (set specified cookie)
- E=var:value (set environment variable var to value)
- F (forbidden - sends a 403 header to the user)
- G (gone - no longer exists)
- H=handler (set handler)
- L (last - stop processing rules)
- N (next - continue processing rules)
- NC (case insensitive)
- NE (do not escape special URL characters in output)
- NS (ignore this rule if the request is a subrequest)
- P (proxy - i.e., apache should grab the remote content specified in the substitution section and return it)
- PT (pass through - use when processing URLs with additional handlers, e.g., mod_alias)
- R (temporary redirect to new URL)
- R=301 (permanent redirect to new URL)
- QSA (append query string from request to substituted URL)
- S=x (skip next x rules)
- T=mime-type (force specified mime type)

Comment: Thanks for response. Yes, mod_rewrite is enabled  of course :) I dont see any new solutions on that URL that you posted that I could use  :(

Comment: One big thing: is apache project directory set directly to Your project catalog (eg /var/www/html/) or to pub catalog (/var/www/html/pub)?

Comment: website is directly in /public_html folder if thats what you mean

Comment: Im asking about directory specified in apache vhost to  this project

Comment: I confirmed with my hosting, the doc root is public_html where the magento files are

Comment: I see. Im asking cause there in pub directory is also .htaccess file that should be changed if projects root is set to pub. Any other Rewrites are working?

Comment: No :(, none of the rewrite urls that I tried worked for me : (

Comment: Even for index.php? If no one - even easiest one - rewrite doesnt works, it is probably something with server config.

Comment: Im sorry, Im not sure I understand, what do you mean for index.php ? that url rewrite works fine, index.php is taken out of the magento urls on the frontend.  Im having problem with doing url rewrites from old domain to new one, with changing only domain base name, but keeping the url path.  You can see in my original question what approaches I tried, but they didnt work.

Comment: I just edit my post

Comment: I dont have enough reputation to upvote yet, I will come back and upvote it later. Thank you. You are my hero! : )) It is strange though, the example code that I have in original question, has worked more than 2-3 times on other, older projects that I worked on, I dont know why it didnt work this time. Your solution did work though. Thanks a million!

Comment: one more question, regarding solution provided by you. Do you know if these redirects  are considered a proper 301 redirects? will this help me not lose all the old backlinks and SEO juice?

Comment: Im glad I could help You ;) I just edit my post with description of parameters you can use